# unwind segue for multiple views

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I am working on an app in Xcode, using modal segues to navigate forwards and using unwind segues to go back to the previous view and also to the home view. However, the segue is just not working when I open up the simulator, no errors are shown and I have used the same approach to unwind segue as is used in the Apple To-do list tutorial, so not sure why this isn't working.

Below is my .h file for one of the views I want to unwind from:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XYZBonBonoftheDayViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *BBoD;

- (IBAction)unwindBBoD:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;


@end
```

Here is my .m file from the same view:

```
#import "XYZBonBonoftheDayViewController.h"

@interface XYZBonBonoftheDayViewController ()

@end

@implementation XYZBonBonoftheDayViewController

- (IBAction)unwindBBoD:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

If anyone could help, this would be immensely helpful! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: They are not views, they are called view controllers. Please add more details about your problem. Did you connect the segue properly in storyboard?

Comment: You say that the code is for a controller you want to "unwind from" -- the unwind method (the IBAction with a UIStoryboardSegue parameter) should be in a controller you're "unwinding to". Also, what did you hook up the unwind segue to? A button? The controller itself?

Comment: Thanks for replying, apologies for my poor diction, pretty new to all this :)

Yes I am 100% sure that the segue was connected properly, the unwind segue was hooked up to a "back" button, just to go back to the page before. 

So as I want to simply revert to the previous page, should I put the code into the files for that previous page as opposed to the current one?

Comment: All sorted, thanks very much for your help mate!